# Click on class is not working after template render from laravel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel

I am using Jquery ajax to get template from Laravel,

```
        $(".menugroupbutton").on('click', function() {
    
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "/menu/renderitems",
                    data: {item_group: this.id },
                    type: "POST",
                    success:function(data){
                        $data = $(data); // the HTML content that controller has produced
                        $('#itemcontainer').hide().html($data).fadeIn();
                    }
                });
            });
        };
```

Here is HTML which is currently in current blade template,

```
 <div class="row" style="padding-left: 15px" id="itemcontainer">
  @include('pages.menu.renderitems')
 </div>
```

the template which going to be rendered on menugroupbutton click is

```
@foreach($items as $i)
<div class="col-lg-2 bg-light-info px-6 py-8 rounded-xl mr-2 mb-2 click2add">
    <a href="#" class="text-secondary font-weight-bold font-size-h6 itemid" id="{{$i->item_id}}">{{$i->item_name}}</a></br>
    <a href="#" class="text-info font-weight-bold font-size-h6">{{$i->item_price}}</a>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Here is click2add event,

```
$('.click2add').on( 'click', function () {
console.log('test');
});
```

I have one more onclick event on class **click2add**.

Now problem is,

When first time page is loaded, my click event on class **click2add** is working fine, means it show test in console
But when i render template(which have **click2add** class) with .menugroupbutton, **click2add** event is no more working, no console log of test.

How can I make click event working on render template as well?

Thanks,

Comment: Problem is resolved with binding,
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0):

**Your jQuery code should be:**

```
$('#itemcontainer').html($data).fadeIn(); //Remove hide()
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajtri/g8oz3pm0/5/)

Hope this will be useful.

Comment: Hi, No that is not an issue, i have updated the question with click2add event when the page is freshly loaded, it works, but when content is rendered, click2add does not work.